# PHP variable in an <iframe>

Tags: php

I have a PHP script where i echo an iframe. I want a variable inside of that. I think this is the right script:

PHP:

```
echo "<style>body{margin: 0}</style><iframe 
src='WEBURL.php? 
nme=$db_name' style='height: 100vh; width: 100vw; border: none; margin: 
0;'>";
```

HTML:

```
<?php echo $nme;?>
```

When i run the PHP script i get an error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: nme

Whats wrong?

Comment: Did you mean `$_GET["nme"]`?

Comment: @David Thank You! I ended up going with `echo $_GET['nme']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `src` is `WEBURL.php?nme=$db_name` which is using a $_GET parameter. To print that out on the screen you can do

```
<?php echo $_GET['nme']; ?>
```

You may want to also strip the content to prevent XSS.